# How to query and sort a complex type consisting of IEnumerable<T> using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Trying to figure out how to query an `IEnumerable<T>` using LINQ. The following simple example *without* IEnumerable works fine:

```
    class Category
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public NameValue SubCategory { get; set; }
    }

    class NameValue
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }


    private static void testLinq()
    {
        Category[] categories = {
            new Category { Title ="Abc", SubCategory =  new NameValue {  Name = "A", Value = "5"} },
            new Category { Title ="Xyz", SubCategory = new NameValue { Name = "B", Value = "10" } }
        };

        IEnumerable<Category> q = categories.OrderBy(c => c.Title).ThenBy(c => c.SubCategory.Name);

        foreach (Category c in q)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", c.Title, c.SubCategory.Name);
        }
    }
```

When I change the signature to have an `IENumerable<NameValue>` instead then I cannot access `c.SubCategory.Name`:

```
    class Category
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<NameValue> SubCategory { get; set; }
    }

// For example, below does not compile:    
IEnumerable<Category> q = categories.OrderBy(c => c.Title).ThenBy(c => c.SubCategory.Name);

// Also, this initialization of course won't work either 
Category[] categories = {
                new Category { Title ="Abc", SubCategory =  new NameValue {  Name = "A", Value = "5"} },
                new Category { Title ="Xyz", SubCategory = new NameValue { Name = "B", Value = "10" } }
            };
```

The error is:

*IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Do I need to do a cast of some sort?

Update:
Output should be something like:

```
Abc (category)
  A (sub)
  B (sub)
  C (...)
Xyz
  B
  K
  M
Xyz2
  A
  Q
  Z
```

In SQL I would do like something like this:

```
SELECT c.Title, s.Name, s.Value FROM Categories c 
    INNER JOIN  SubCategory s ON
    c.CategoryID = s.CategoryID
ORDER BY c.Title, s.Name -- sorting first on Category.Title, then on SubCategory.Name
```

Comment: IEnumerable kind of represents a view of a collection. You're already performing Linq operations on a collection (categories). What is the problem here? Why do you expect the enumerable to contain a definition for Name when it is a collection of NameValue objects?

Comment: `IEnumerable<NameValue>` does not contain a definition for 'Name' as `IEnumerable<NameValue>` is a collection of `NameValue` objects. You need to go through it's elements to access `Name`.

Comment: The reason why I want c.SubCategory.Name (or the equivalent that works IEnumerable) is that I want to sort query with multiple fields OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)...

Comment: You understand that by wrapping NameValue in IEnumerable<> means that you're declaring that SubCategory is a _collection_ of objects, not just a _single_ object, right?

Comment: @john yes I do :) - I am just struggling with the syntax for doing the subsequent sort, i.e. ThenBy when I have a collection instead of the single object.

Comment: Then why are you trying to access Name as if it's a single object? How do you hope to sort a parent category based on its (many) subcategories?

Comment: To rephrase - what would be the correct syntax for accessing/sorting a collection in linq query, i.e ThenBy(....)?

Comment: Multiple order clause works fine as long as you have property directly accessible on the object. If the property itself is a collection you can not use it in order by clause. Why do you want to sort by collection property ? How does is help the sorting of the Category collection?

Comment: What you wish you to achieve is logically incorrect, and thus technically not possible.

Comment: @Sha I think you're missing the point I'm making. We have no idea what you expec tthe input/output to be. What you're doing seems strange to me, and you don't tell us how your subcategories affect the sorting of the category objects. How do you expect us to help without this information?

Comment: If you have property which is collection, it will have multiple objects into it. Which object among them you want to sort based on?

Comment: @john - I will update question and try to explain better. 2 sec.

Comment: In then by you can use any other property of Category which is not collection at least...

Comment: @Sha You also need to change `categories` init code because that won't compile otherwise.

Comment: OK. Looking at your edited question, you've misunderstood the OrderBy / ThenBy relationship. OrderBy / ThenBy might be something like OrderBy(FirstName).ThenBy(LastName). There isn't a Linq method that will sort a parent object and then it's child objects. Linq is a view, all you get out is an IEnumerable<T>. It _doesn't mutate_ T.

Comment: Based on your updates you need to first order by category title. And then loop thru the collection of categories and sort the SubCategories property of each category by name. You can not use thenby here for sure. You might want to create and extension method to centralize the logic.

Comment: @john - ahh okay. I am coming from the SQL world and had in mind that I could do something like `SELECT c.Title, s.Name, s.Value FROM Categories c 
 INNER JOIN  SubCategory s ON
 c.CategoryID = s.CategoryID
ORDER BY c.Title, s.Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SubCategory` will be a collection so you cannot do it using `ThenBy`. You need to order the `Category`(s) and then order their `SubCategory`(s) like this. Note I added two `SubCategory`(s) to the first `Category` but their order is not correct. After we order them, then they will be correct:

```
Category[] categories = {
    new Category { Title ="Abc", SubCategory = new List<NameValue> 
        {  new NameValue {  Name = "B", Value = "5"},
           new NameValue {  Name = "A", Value = "5"} } },
    new Category { Title ="Xyz", SubCategory = new List<NameValue> 
        { new NameValue { Name = "A", Value = "10" } } }};

// First order by categories   
var cats = categories.OrderBy(c => c.Title)
    // Then create a new category and order by sub categories 
    .Select(x => new Category { Title = x.Title, 
                     SubCategory = x.SubCategory.OrderBy(y => y.Name) });
```

Comment: this worked for me, i.e. doing the double OrderBy(). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can get away with only sorting the children when you need to use them, sorting by the parent and then sorting the children upon use like this would be fairly efficient:

```
public void DisplayA(A value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value.Name);
    foreach (var child in value.Children.OrderBy(c => c.Name))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("- {0}", child.Name));
    }
}
```

Or if you want to avoid that, you could add a sorted property to the class. Since it's Linq, it will only be evaluated when you iterate through the list.

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<B> Children { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<B> SortedChildren { get { return Children.OrderBy(ca => ca.Name); } }
}

public class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If they don't work for you, you could try these, but they won't be so efficient since you're creating *new* objects.

```
// This will flatten it into a single object, sorted by one field and the the other. Since this is Linq, it will create these new flattened objects each time you iterate through the IEnumerable.
public IEnumerable<FlattenedA> GetSortedFlattened(IEnumerable<A> collection)
{
    var flattened = collection.SelectMany(a => a.Children.Select(ca => new FlattenedA() { Name = a.Name, SubName = ca.Name }));
    var sorted = flattened.OrderBy(f => f.Name).ThenBy(f => f.SubName);
    return sorted;
}

// This will return objects of A, where the child enumerable has been replaced with an OrderBy. Again this will return new objects each time you iterate through. Only when you iterate through the children will they be sorted.
public IEnumerable<A> GetSortedNonFlattened(IEnumerable<A> collection)
{
    var withSortedChildren = collection.Select(a => new A() { Name = a.Name, Children = a.Children.OrderBy(ca => ca.Name) });
    var sorted = withSortedChildren.OrderBy(a => a.Name);
    return sorted;
}

public class FlattenedA
{
    public string Name { get;set }
    public string SubName { get; set; }
}

public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<B> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @john - I could not get SortedChildren to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

when you are setting it as IEnumerable you can't do this

`SubCategory =  new NameValue {  Name = "A", Value = "5"}`

you should use some implementation of IEnumerable, 
like List<>

so it should be something like this

`SubCategory =  new List<NameValue>{new NameValue {  Name = "A", Value = "5"}, addmore here};`

and for your order linq, i would do this,

```
var OrderedCategories = categories.select(g => 
new Category{ Name = g.Name, subcategories = g.subcategories.orderby(h => h.Name) });
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because your `SubCategory` now is no longer a simple single instance of `NameValue`, but rather an enumeration of those.  So now you need to specify how to `.ThenBy` over a collection of `.Name`s.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question... at all.

Comment: @john I'm explaining the compiler error that OP is receiving.  The data models and exactly how to order doesn't seem to match the SQL given as golden standard.  Too many assumptions to answer.  So I'm just explaining compiler error.

Comment: OK, but this would be better as a comment (it has already been addressed in the comments, anyway)